# Change Git bash directory using sh script

Tags: git

I am trying to run a simple sh script in git bash with the following commands:

```
mkdir "last"
cd last
```

and execute

```
$sh myscript.sh
```

I expect that git bash change the directory to last but it is still in the same directory.

I am using windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You start a new process that changes the directory
- The calling process ( your shell ) is not influenced by that

You should call the contained statements in your current bash with `. myscript.sh` to have that process change its directory.